# Implement (POCO) struct property accessor in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to implement an interface from my C++/CLI dll in C#. But I am having issues with return value optimization in C++ I guess. Consider

```
// BVHTree.cpp:
public value struct Vector3
{
    float X, Y, Z;
};

public value struct TriangleWithNormal
{
    Vector3 A, B, C, Normal;
};

public interface class IBVHNode
{
    property TriangleWithNormal Triangle { TriangleWithNormal get(); } // among others
    property bool IsLeaf { bool get(); } // can implement this
};
```

---

```
// BVHNode.cs:
public class BVHNode : IBVHNode // Error: member TriangleWithNormal* IBVHNode.get_Triangle(TriangleWithNormal*) not implemented (sth. along those lines)
{
    public TriangleWithNormal Triangle { get { return new TriangleWithNormal(); } }
    public bool IsLeaf { get { return true; } }
}
```

It complains `BVNode` didn't implement `IBVHNode`. My last resort would be to access it via a regular method or using unsafe mode like visual studio suggests:

```
public TriangleWithNormal* get_Triangle(TriangleWithNormal* t) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Is there any way to still implement it in property syntax (apart from making `TriangleWithNormal` a `ref class`...)?

**Update 1** Seems to be that implementing a method `TriangleWithNormal GetTriangle()` fails for the same reasons. You can however use it like `void GetTriangle(TriangleWithNormal%);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the error was gone after I lived some build cycles with my `void GetTriangle(TriangleWithNormal%);` workaround. Be it a wonder or more likely a silent clean build, upon commenting in the errorneous property trying to reproduce the error condition one more time, it compiled out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked for me, once I fixed a couple minor syntax errors (`;` after class declarations in C++/CLI, missing the word `bool` as the return type of `IsLeaf.get()`), and defined the Vector3 type.

I guessed at how you have Vector3 defined, it's not a standard class that I'm familiar with. Where is it defined? Is it a managed class, managed struct, or unmanaged? (I defined it as `public value struct Vector3 { double x, y, z; };` for my test.)

As I said, there's minor syntax errors in your C++/CLI code you posted here. Those two errors give very distinct compile errors, so I'm assuming those are typos in the transcription from Visual Studio to the web. Are there any other changes between what you posted and the actual code?

---

In addition, I was not able to get the error message you reported, `member TriangleWithNormal* IBVHNode.get_Triangle(TriangleWithNormal*) not implemented`. I always end up with the compile error `error CS0535: 'CSharpTest.BVHNode' does not implement interface member 'CppCLITest.IBVHNode.Triangle'`.

The property you've shown doesn't take a parameter, but the compiler error shows a method `get_Triangle` that takes a parameter of type `TriangleWithNormal*`. Do you have another declaration of the property somewhere, or a declaration of that method explicitly?

---

I think I may have it. If I try to declare the C++/CLI property as an indexed property, then I get a method signature similar to what you're seeing.

In your actual code, do you have something like this:

```
property TriangleWithNormal Triangle[TriangleWithNormal] { TriangleWithNormal get(TriangleWithNormal input); }
```

That's an indexed property, which C# doesn't allow you to implement. (C# does allow one indexed property, `this[]`, but only that one.)

When I try to implement that in C#, it requires me to explicitly implement the property's backing method, rather than implement it as a C# property.

```
public TriangleWithNormal get_Triangle(TriangleWithNormal input)
{
    return new TriangleWithNormal();
}
```

Make the indexed property a regular one, and this should work fine for you.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the errors... I hopefully fixed them. Actually I didn't try out to compile that particular example but have similar code to work with. And of course it gave me the same compiler error you mentioned, I just came up with a more-to-the-point description.

Comment: You get the syntax for `get_Triangle` if you hit `Alt`+`Enter` under the squiggles in Visual Studio, it provides you with the default implementation mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure which squiggles you're referring to, I can't get Alt-Enter to do anything other than beep at me. I'm aware that properties are implemented as methods behind the scenes, but I'd expect the signature to be `TriangleWithNormal get_Triangle()`, not `TriangleWithNormal get_Triangle(TriangleWithNormal)`. The property doesn't take a parameter, so why would the implementing method?

Comment: Is it possible you have an indexed property in C++/CLI? It's valid C++/CLI and valid CLR, but there's no C# syntax for it. See edit.

Comment: Ok... this is strange. It was the exact property to implement like I posted in my question, unlike indexer syntax like supposed in your edit. I had it running with my `void GetTriangle(TriangleWithNormal%);` workaround and just tried to switch back to property syntax to see the actual error. It is gone, it compiles error free now. I wonder if it enough to just have Visual Studio perform a clean build... regardless: Thanks for your effort!